# SQL Index on Multiple tables, can it be done?

Tags: sql, indexing

Been searching for a solution for a while now,

go to (1) or (2) to skip description,
first i will explain the situation.

My firm have upgraded our erp. system, my primary work is to create lists used by others in the firm, i take all my data from this systems database
during upgrade we got some data converted to match the new version, some of it was left behind, some of it was not tampered with and just directly exported to the new database,
its on a separate server, 
basically its a success, the new ERP. system works as supposed,
however a lot of my lists have been broken, 
the data my lists use is missing/partly_missing/all_there

okay so the problem is missing data i need from the old database, okay a union on new and old database should be able to do that, however i do not want duplicate records, "data that was converted to the new database also exist in the old database" therefore two fields could exist "they do, i tried it"

so 2. version of my solution

i am lacking primary keys "iseries database" so i went concatting a combination of feilds making a uniqe key, "takes too long to explain how i did that"
however it ends up in me making a view with a union on two databases, making sure no records exist two times,

(1)
so this is what i got now,
a view of the combination of old and new table data
all built with checks on a "uniqe" key....
every time i need data that has been effected of the upgrade i must run a expensive query on each table, "some using these views more than 40 times"
(Question1) how can i "cost effective" take data from two different schemas/databases and bind together?

(2)
the only thing i can think of giving me this performance is to make indexes instead of these views that i built, however until now i haven't been able to find any information on how to,
(Question2) Can i create a index over two tables,

my database is as/400 - iseries
however i am interested in a solution up against any database type,
i am very flexible with resources

:EDIT:
code that is used to create view with slight modification,

```
SELECT

CTCONO,
CTDIVI,
CTSTCO,
CTSTKY,
CTLNCD,
CTTX40,
CTTX15,
CTPARM,
CTTXID,
CTRGDT,
CTRGTM,
CTLMDT,
CTCHNO,
CTCHID

FROM NEWDB.CSYTAB
UNION
SELECT * FROM OLDDB.CSYTAB

WHERE ( CTCONO,CTDIVI,CTSTCO,CTSTKY,CTLNCD ) NOT IN
(
SELECT A.CTCONO,A.CTDIVI,A.CTSTCO,A.CTSTKY,A.CTLNCD FROM NEWDB.CSYTAB A, OLDDB.CSYTAB B
WHERE A.CTCONO = B.CTCONO
AND A.CTDIVI = B.CTDIVI
AND A.CTSTCO = B.CTSTCO
AND A.CTSTKY = B.CTSTKY
AND A.CTLNCD = B.CTLNCD

)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a new table that stores the value of your expensive query, then if you're going to always ignore the older data in general if there's a record in the new DB for it. Then just add in some triggers to update this new table when the other tables get updated.

Perhaps, a better question would be to provide your schema, and current expensive query then ask for people to help make it faster.

Edit: now you have posted your table I see one thing you could improve, make the second part of your query this:

```
...
UNION
SELECT * FROM OLDDB.CSYTAB B
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM NEWDB.CSYTAB A
    WHERE A.CTCONO = B.CTCONO
        AND A.CTDIVI = B.CTDIVI
        AND A.CTSTCO = B.CTSTCO
        AND A.CTSTKY = B.CTSTKY
        AND A.CTLNCD = B.CTLNCD
    )
```

Then provided you have a single index that spans { CTCONO,CTDIVI,CTSTCO,CTSTKY,CTLNCD } in the NEWDB.CSYTAB then it should be much better performance than what you're getting currently.

Comment: Making a new table would solve my problem, the problem is here that i would have to implement a lot of changes to my lists, making huge and complex queries even more complex, "i need to join with the "ctrl" table then", however good suggestion, i have also posted some code now, thanks

Comment: This is just one table, i choose this cause its relatively small 7k records only but some of the tables are millions of records "above 20 at least", this table got like 15 columns, some got much much more, i cant test your example cause top is not supported in ibm iseries "not Tsql" however i belive you can do the NOT EXISTS, should this query give me a better performance or is just better formatted

Comment: even without the top 1 it should get better performance than your code, but otherwise there's not a lot you can do

Comment: I was thinking about your table solution, since it gives me the performance and controle i need, i could make the table "instead of the index" and then make a view that joins in the data from the right places, little like i do today, hmm any know of some query analyzers that is free and works with all kind of sql servers?

Comment: You could try LINQpad (http://www.linqpad.net/), it's free and is what I use when I don't have a management tool to connect to a sql db

Comment: Would love to use it, looks nice, however sad as it is we still run old scool asp "with vbscript" so linq is out of the question, "i know its freaking cool, boss says nooo"

Comment: LINQpad doesn't just do linq, it you can write c# / vb.net in it or you can use it as a SQL query tool to write raw SQL queries against a database

Comment: Nice, will definitely try it now, :P

Answer (score 10):

The answer is no.

I can't create a index on multiple tables.

My solution would be to make a table instead, and in my case a view also,
or I could just optimize the SQL code.

EDIT

I just learned that in MS (at least the 2012 version) you can create indexed views. So in my case I would turn my views into indexed views, and get a huge performance upgrade.

Comment: YES you can.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017    note that in some on premise versions of sql server the licensing version can be relevant - enterprise vs basic.  The developer edition acts like enterprise so you could get a surprise in your prod environment.

Comment: @SqlSurfer you missed the part where I wrote "my database is as/400".
(so a IBM db2 database)

Comment: I think I posted my comment to the wrong open window  - There should be a badge for that.

Comment: Yes, definitely can. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Robert_Laurini/publication/220649683_Spatial_Multi-Database_Topological_Continuity_and_Indexing_A_Step_Towards_Seamless_GIS_Data_Interoperability/links/54db4fcf0cf2ba88a68fc230/Spatial-Multi-Database-Topological-Continuity-and-Indexing-A-Step-Towards-Seamless-GIS-Data-Interoperability.pdf