# Add index to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create one index with 2 columns each from different tables.

I tried through phpmyadmin interface but with no luck. How can I achieve this with mysql?

Comment: Add more information.

Comment: Duplicate post, refer below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553099/sql-index-on-multiple-tables-can-it-be-done

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only add an index to columns of the same table. So you have to create your two indexes seperately. One for the 2 columns in tableA, and another for the column in tableB.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Indexes are related to a single table, the only thing that come close to what you wish is a JOIN between the two indexed tables, but still, `this is not what you're looking for. Move along`